# named_scope dependent on existence of association is breaking tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :clients, 
    :conditions => "roles_users.role_id = #{Role.find_by_name('client').id}"
end
```

When testing, throws error:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted (etc.)
```

Role fixtures:

```
client:
  name: client
user:
  name: user
```

Apparent problem: Rails is loading this class before it loads fixtures.  When it loads the class it evaluates the named_scope.  There are no roles at that point, so it blows up.

Possible solution:

```
named_scope :clients, 
  lambda { { :conditions => "roles_users.role_id = #{Role.named('client').id}" } }
```

However, I am not pleased with this solution, seeing as it introduces additional complexity and presumably a (small?) performance hit, just so that tests run properly.  I'd like an alternative.  Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you propose is the correct solution.  I would also recommend changing your code to:

```
named_scope :clients, lambda { { :conditions => ['roles_users.role_id = ?', Role.named('client').id } }
```

An alternative might be:

```
named_scope :clients, :joins => :role, :conditions => ['roles.name = ?', 'client']
```

You might also want to think about doing:

```
named_scope :with_role, lambda { |r| { :conditions => ['roles_users.role_id = ?', r.id] } }
```

Or even (for extra points)

```
Role.find_by_name('client').users
```

Anyway, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your first recommendation (security/correctness). But what do you see as the advantage of your second suggestion, the one with :joins => :role? Is it simply for clarity's sake?

Comment: It would achieve the same thing in one query, instead of two.